multiprocessing queues losing reference when passed to worker process
I am creating a multiprocessing Manager as a global variable in the main process and then create a Queue with this manager for each task I want to process. These Queue objects are then passed into a pool of workers, one queue per task.
When these queues are accesses, something is losing its reference, and I can't figure out why:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/net/home/cmosig/miniconda3/envs/env_conda/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 209, in _handle_request
    result = func(c, *args, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/net/home/cmosig/miniconda3/envs/env_conda/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 438, in incref
    raise ke
  File "/net/home/cmosig/miniconda3/envs/env_conda/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 426, in incref
    self.id_to_refcount[ident] += 1
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: '712cf1996780'

Minimal Example:
import multiprocessing as mp
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

GLOBAL_QUEUE_MANAGER = mp.Manager()


def process(queue):
    queue.put("test")
    queue.close()
    return

def job_generator():
    for i in range(10):
        queue = GLOBAL_QUEUE_MANAGER.Queue()
        yield {"queue": queue}


Parallel(n_jobs=3, batch_size=1,
         backend="multiprocessing")(delayed(process)(**p)
                                    for p in job_generator())

EDIT: What I want to avoid is creating all Queue objects for all tasks beforehand as there could be potentially thousands of tasks and I am worried about overhead.
EDIT2: FWIW: worker processes can't create queues as they are deamonic.
The complete implementation: https://github.com/cmosig/sentle/blob/cba4e40782d54df646f16dbaf4dadcc1f058a921/sentle/sentle.py#L622

I'm not sure I understand why you need thousands of queues? Do you create thousands of new processes? Why not re-using queues?

There needs to be one queue per task at least for the lifetime of the task. And there could potentially be thousands of tasks.

I'm still not seeing the necessity. Is every task different, so that it needs a unique queue, because it gets different data? And what exactly is a task? You don't mean workers in your pool, right? A worker can only do one task at at time. So you only need as many queues as you have workers.

Yes, I technically need only one queue per worker, meaning I could create a queue upon init of a worker. joblib unfortunately has no such init function.

(fwiw I solved this by maintaining a dict of queues in the main process, no key error anymore) thanks!
